# How do the serialPersistantFields get accessed by writeObject()

Tags: java

Needed for serialisation, I understand this, but how can stream.defaultWriteObject() actually access these since they are private, static and final.

My lecturer in CS is just not able to explain this (or he just doesn't want to), there is no documentation out there (to my understanding) that explains this mechanism either.

Even an abstract explanation is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we always take to gain access to private fields: reflection. Specifically through `Field.setAccessible(true)`. Here's the code where they do exactly that, from `java.io.ObjectStreamClass`, Java 8:

```
/**
 * Returns serializable fields of given class as defined explicitly by a
 * "serialPersistentFields" field, or null if no appropriate
 * "serialPersistentFields" field is defined.  Serializable fields backed
 * by an actual field of the class are represented by ObjectStreamFields
 * with corresponding non-null Field objects.  For compatibility with past
 * releases, a "serialPersistentFields" field with a null value is
 * considered equivalent to not declaring "serialPersistentFields".  Throws
 * InvalidClassException if the declared serializable fields are
 * invalid--e.g., if multiple fields share the same name.
 */
private static ObjectStreamField[] getDeclaredSerialFields(Class<?> cl)
    throws InvalidClassException
{
    ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = null;
    try {
        Field f = cl.getDeclaredField("serialPersistentFields");
        int mask = Modifier.PRIVATE | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL;
        if ((f.getModifiers() & mask) == mask) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            serialPersistentFields = (ObjectStreamField[]) f.get(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

Comment: Wow, after 11 weeks studying Java; my lecturer didn't even touch on this idea of reflection. In fact; we were taught those visible(?) modifiers are the de facto way of setting if a field is accessible via another method of a different class.

Comment: @FloSuess Nothing wrong with that. I wouldn't consider Reflection a first-semester topic.

Answer (score 1):

By reflection. `ObjectOutputStream` can also access `private static final long serialVersionUID` as well, and `private static void writeObject(...)` and `private static Object readObject(...)` too, and the private `readResolve()/writeReplace()` methods.